# Move a file across site collections with version history

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, csom

I have the need to move a document using **Client Object Model** across site collections in SharePoint Online while retaining its metadata and version history.

The `sp.movecopyutil` methods allows us to move files within a site collection while retaining the item metadata, moderation status, and version history. However the `sp.movecopyutil` does not work properly when we try to move a document across site collections (Moderation status and version history are not retained).

Is there any other API or methods available to move documents across site collection while retaining the metadata, moderation status, and with version history?

If there is no standard **API** available for this, what would be the best way to go about achieving this move action?

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to find a solution using Client Object Model.
However, using third party solutions such as ShareGate with it's powershell functions you can accomplish this.

Comment: I agree not an great answer, but I thought I'd offer an option after 2 years of no luck when I was having the same problem.