# Migrate documents to another site collection with versions using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have two site collection on SharePoint online.

I want to create web job to move all files to another site collection along with version.

I have created one console application and written code in `managed CSOM` to copy all files to another site collection but versions are missing.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Following is my code

```
       private static void CreateFile(Folder folder, ClientContext sourceContext, ClientContext destContext, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file, Web sourceWeb, Web destWeb)
    {
        string newLocation = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            ClientResult<Stream> data = file.OpenBinaryStream();
            ListItem oldItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
            FieldCollection fields = oldItem.ParentList.Fields;
            sourceContext.Load(file);
            sourceContext.Load(oldItem);
            sourceContext.Load(fields);
            sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();


            newLocation = file.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(sourceWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl);
            FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
            fileInfo.ContentStream = data.Value;
            fileInfo.Url = newLocation;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newFile = folder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
            ListItem newItem = newFile.ListItemAllFields;
            destContext.Load(newFile);
            destContext.Load(newItem);
            destContext.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach (Field field in fields)
            {
                if (!field.ReadOnlyField && !field.Hidden && field.InternalName != "Attachments" && field.Title != "Content Type")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        newItem[field.InternalName] = oldItem[field.InternalName];
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {                            
                    }
                }
            }
            newItem.Update();
            if (newFile.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None)
                newFile.CheckIn("New File", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
            destContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should you add your code to can help you faster

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure that the versioning has been enabled on both libraries.

If the issue is related to code , Try to use the following code to can Migrate Sharepoint document with version to using CSOM

```
int fileCount = sourceFolder.Files.Count();
for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
 {
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File sourceFile = sourceFolder.Files[i];
FileVersionCollection sourceFileVersions = sFile.Versions; sContext.Load(sourceFileVersions, fileVersions => fileVersions.Include( version => version.Url, version => version.VersionLabel, version => version.CheckInComment )); try { sContext.ExecuteQuery(); } catch (Exception e) { //handle exception   
 }


foreach (FileVersion fileVer in sourceFileVersions)
{ UploadFiles(sContext.Url + "/" + fileVer.Url, targetFolder, sourceItem["FileLeafRef"].ToString());
}
}

private static void UploadFiles(string sourceFileUrl, Folder targetFolder, string fileName)
 {
 FileCreationInformation targetFileVersionCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation(); targetFileVersionCreationInfo.Overwrite = true; try { WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(sourceFileUrl); request.Credentials = sContext.Credentials; using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) { using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) { byte[] verBuffer = new byte[32768]; using (MemoryStream versionMS = new MemoryStream()) { int read; while ((read = stream.Read(verBuffer, 0, verBuffer.Length)) > 0) { versionMS.Write(verBuffer, 0, read); } versionMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); targetFileVersionCreationInfo.ContentStream = versionMS; tContext.RequestTimeout = System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite; targetFileVersionCreationInfo.Url = targetFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + fileName; Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File targetVersionFile = targetFolder.Files.Add(targetFileVersionCreationInfo); try { tContext.ExecuteQuery(); } catch (Exception ex) { //handle exception   
 } } } } } catch (Exception ex) { //handle exception   
 }
 }
```

- Check the full code at [Migrate Sharepoint document with version to Sharepoint online using CSOM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakhiguha/2015/12/06/migrate-sharepoint-document-with-version-to-sharepoint-online-using-csom/)
- Check also a similar thread at [Move a file across site collections with version history](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163965/move-a-file-across-site-collections-with-version-history)
- Also, I suggest a simple method without code to **Move** not Copy the files via `Explorer View` between document libraries this will keep versions only at **Move**.